# Redirecting crawlers

Tags: php

I have an online tool that keeps track of tasks and users completing tasks. As a part of the process I record `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. However, once in a while I get visits from various bots and crawlers. How do I gently redirect them elsewhere without "hurting their feelings"?

I was thinking I'd net to build an array with bot names and run each AGENT info against it, and if found in array, redirect.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: If you do so, don't forget to send a `header("Vary: User-Agent");`

Comment: Giving different content to real users and crawlers will probably make large search engines punish you by lowering your site's rank in their search results.

Comment: Oh, I need to check this out. I'm not familiar with "Vary". Thanks.

Comment: @ThiefMaster You're right, and that's why I am looking for a solution that will not backfire.

Comment: Also you can make a MySQL table with user agents, and have a column "crawler", you can then run a query against the database to check whether it is a bot or not - much easier than managing an array inside you PHP script.

Comment: There is no such solution. At least google is known to access sites with regular user-agents from IPs outside the regular google netblocks. So you cannot know for sure if it's crawler or not.

Answer (score 6):

If not done already, you could get rid of most crawlers by utilizing the robots.txt file. [See here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) This is not strictly adhered to, however. Those who keep on crawling can be IP banned. You can do this on Linux with iptables. Example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s IP-ADDRESS -j DROP
```

Comment: I have robots.txt that mainly bans some "bad" bots, and disallow going to certain directories. Can I also add a page that they can not visit? The page is dynamic and always starts with the same prefix: /plan... like /planDWXWS5WsD ? Thanks.

Comment: `disallow /plan*` might work with google but wildcards are not supported by dumb crawlers. You should combine that with rel="nofollow" suffixes at each link [http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569).

Comment: Yeah, I have rel="nofollow" but I think some users repost the links and that's how I get "uninvited" visitors. I think for now I'll try wildcard solution and monitor further to see if I get bots anyway.

Comment: The meta tag `<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />` can be added within the page. Like I said, not all crawlers are to be trusted. If I were you, I'd ban all, except major ones (i.e Google,  Bing etc).

Answer (score 3):

Make list with [needed spiders](http://www.user-agents.org/) and make redirect with this code:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: NEED_URL_HERE');
```

Actualy you can use [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html) or [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) (if crawler use it)

```
 User-agent: *
 Disallow: /
```

**UPD:** If you use this for SEO (cloacking) you can be punished by search engine, be care.

Comment: Can I use something like: User-agent: *
 Disallow: /plan if the page that I am trying to protect starts with /plan, like in /planDWXWS5WsD

Comment: i mean `.htaccess` course. You can disallow use this code: User-agent: * Disallow: /plan*